# gdb attach : No such file or directory erros

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm trying to debug my program using the gdb attach command and I'm currently having a little trouble.

```
attach: No such file or directory.
Attaching to process 23224
Reading symbols from /lib64/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib64/librt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libdl.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libm.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libkrb5.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libkrb5.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib64/libcom_err.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libcom_err.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libresolv.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libresolv.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libselinux.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libselinux.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libnss_files.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

When I add a breakpoint and use run to execute，It stays in this state.

```
[New Thread 0x7fffe38fc700 (LWP 3343)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe2efb700 (LWP 3344)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe24fa700 (LWP 3345)]
```

this is my computer configuration

```
gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC) 
x86_64-redhat-linux
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-47.el6
```

Please give me some ideas, thanks!

Comment: Could you show how do you use gdb attach command?

Comment: sudo gdb attach pid

Answer (score 0):

> `sudo gdb attach pid`

That is *not a thing*. This command tells GDB to load an executable file called `attach`, and load a `core` file named `pid`.

What you want (replace `$pid` with actual numeric process id of the desired target process):

```
sudo gdb -p $pid
```

or alternatively:

```
sudo gdb -ex 'attach $pid'
```

Comment: what is the difference between gdb attach  pid and gdb -p pid ?I want to know how it works.

Comment: "what is the difference" -- one doesn't work, the other one does what you want. Typing "random" words on command line without understanding what they mean (in that context) is not a recipe for success.